# Laravel фильтр по нескольким параметрам

Tags: laravel

подскажите как реализовать фильтр пользователей по 10 параметрам?

пробую так

```
$gender = 0;
if (Auth::user()->attributes->gender == 1){
    $gender = 2; //Выводим деушек , если текущий пользователь парень
}
if (Auth::user()->attributes->gender == 2){
    $gender = 1; //Выводим парней , если текущий пользователь девушка
}

$users = User::filter($request->all(),$gender)
        ->orderBy('users.id','asc')->get();
```

но не работает ничего

```
public function scopeFilter($query,$request,$gender)
    {
        $query->leftJoin('user_attributes','user_attributes.user_id',
             '=','users.id');

        $query->select('users.id','users.slug','users.name',
            'user_attributes.fullname','user_attributes.age',
            'user_attributes.avatar',
            'user_attributes.city');
        $query->where('user_attributes.gender','=', $gender);
        return $query;
}
```

Comment: Это где Вы такой метод `filter` нашли в eloquent?

Comment: это scopeFilter

Comment: я не знаю как мне добавлять условия и мой код не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никогда не делал вот таким образом. Я бы сделал как-то так:

```
return $model->whereHas('attributes', function($query) use ($gender) {
   $query->where('gender', $gender);
})
->with('attributes')
->get();
```

Ну при этом, естественно, должен быть метод  arrtibutes() в модели, с описанием связи с атрибутами.

Comment: да, я так и сделал, только чуток по другому